# Creating scss variable in config.rb for scss files

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sass, compass-sass

How to define a SCSS variable in Config.rb for SCSS file[ COMPASS project ]

**My Use-case**

In Config.rb file something like

```
a = true
```

In style.scss i like to use the variable like

```
@if a == true{
     background: #fff;
} 
@else {
   background: #000;
}
```

One of the solution 
http://worldhousefinder.com/?p=124141

But its not worked for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write ruby code in css file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301195/how-to-write-ruby-code-in-css-file)

Answer (score 2):

You can't/shouldn't do this. You will precompile your assets so there is no way of dynamically adapting to changing variables. This might work for your config.rb variable, but it is a bad pattern to use and you'd have to recompile your assets every time you change the variable, this defeats the purpose of doing if else checks in your sass.

A much easier approach is to either add a class `.active` `.inactive` on your elements (body). Or output inline css in your head for things like custom colors etc depending on users that are signed in.

What are you trying to do? It sounds like something you'd do to check whether you are in production or development? In which case you could do something like:

```
<body class='<%= "development" if Rails.env == 'development' %>'>
```

or even

```
<body <%= "style='background-color: red;'" if Rails.env == 'development' %>
```

You should never need to use ruby in your css and javascript, if you find yourself doing it you are probably approaching it in the wrong way. At least that is what I have found after many attempts to do this nicely.

p.s. data-attributes are a very effective way of passing variables, etc to javascript

Comment: Thx for your reply, And yes i want to regenerate stylesheets. I need this to create **RTL and LTR ** stylesheet with a single scss file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you looked at [variables](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/#variables) and [mixins](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/#mixins)?

If you're REALLY trying to pass outside variables to SASS, you must understand that it's not aware of your config file when it's compiling CSS. [According to Nathan Weizenbaum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sass-lang/sGgDimoDP64/osFd0YLlgnMJ) (one of the main developers of Haml), the best way to do it is by creating custom **[user-defined functions](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#adding_custom_functions)**.

If you go that route (again, quoting Nathan):

> You'll want to make sure that your stylesheets
>   get regenerated whenever the data changes. You can do so by calling
>   `Sass::Plugin.force_update_stylesheets`.

Comment: Thx for your reply, And yes i want to regenerate stylesheets. I need this to create **RTL and LTR ** stylesheet with a single scss file.